# How to clear an Android ListView and populate it with new data?

Tags: android, listview, sqlite

I have a spinner and a listview in the same Activity. The listview is loaded with a list of items. i want when user clicks on the item from spinner the listview will be clear and new listview will load according to item chooses in spinner

```
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listviewxml, video));

       ListView lv=getListView();

       lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

[image]

Please tell how to do this?

i am not able to clear the listview

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have passed a **List or an Array to the Adapter**, then

```
// Clear collection..
collection.clear();
// Add data to collection..
collection.add();
// Refresh your listview..
listview.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

(These codes are like pseudo code, your syntax may vary)

Answer (score 6):

When a new item is chosen in your `Spinner` use on your `ListView` adapter :

```
    //Clear existing items
    listAdapter.clear();
    //Add new items
    listAdapter.addAll(collectionOfItems);
    //Notify that the data has changed
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just try setting a null adapter to the listview. So you could just do :

```
    lv.setadapter(null);
```

Comment: It didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You should store a reference to the Adapter and perform clear on that. Then you can add more items again using the Adapter.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listviewxml, video);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

then later use

```
adapter.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. its works for me:)

```
 YourArrayList_Object.clear(); // clear the listview
```

**or**

```
ArrayList<DetailsForCallhistoryListActivity> callhistory_details_list;
```

**then**

```
callhistory_details_list.clear();
```