# Is there a way to clear a firebase recycler adapter so that it again loads new data

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

Everytime when the onResume() method is called the adapter contains duplicate data in the recycler view. I wanted to clear the list everytime the onResume() method is called and again fetch the new data is this possible ?

My code structure looks like this

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        ...

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    } 

@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapter.startListening();
    }
```

Comment: in `onResume` above `adapter.startListening();` line add `arrayList.clear` which array you bind in adapter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear an Android ListView and populate it with new data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310851/how-to-clear-an-android-listview-and-populate-it-with-new-data)

Comment: @Ali Firebase RecyclerAdapter doesn't have the method .clear() hence i'm not able to clear it

Comment: @DipeshPatil I didn't understand. Can you please show me bind data code.

Comment: @Ali i updated my code please have a look

Comment: May I know what is this: `PostThumb` and where you from pass this?

Comment: @Ali since i'm not able to post the entire code i'll tell you in short basically this code is displaying a grid of images  and it does that perfectly. And further when i click on a particular image i get to see that image on a new activity. Now when i press the back button and come back to the activity where i have this grid of images, the `onResume()` is called and it displays duplicate data in adapter. So i wanted to clear all the data first and then again load the new set of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Comment: Try my 2nd solution which I update in answer & then inform me.

Comment: I didnt understand the second solution can you please eleborate it ?

Comment: The second solution works can you please explain what does `adapter.notifyDataSetChange();` do ?

Comment: If any data update in the `adapter` class then it's updated only new data didn't repeat old data.